# random movement of points in an Area

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to make 10 random point which moves randomly in space (N,S,E,W).

For example, each point must randomly select a direction(N,S,E,w) and move fixed distance and again select a direction and move a fixed distance (non stop).

```
clear all;
X=200;
Y=200;
Num=10;
A=[1 2 3 4];
Loc_Nodes=zeros(2,Num);
 for i=1:2
%       Loc_Nodes(i,:) = randperm(X,Num);
%  end
    Loc_Nodes(1,:)=X*rand(1,Num);
    Loc_Nodes(2,:)=Y*rand(1,Num);

 end
scatter (Loc_Nodes(1,:),Loc_Nodes(2,:),'mo');
drawnow;
pause(0.1)
```

Comment: Help with what? Please, read [ask]

Comment: I would try to come-up with a matlab code (while you're trying to clarify your question) but consider using [NetLogo](http://www.netlogoweb.org/launch#http://www.netlogoweb.org/assets/modelslib/Sample%20Models/Biology/Ant%20Lines.nlogo) (this is a demo, find it on the homepage), as it is built to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. You are currently struggling to define how the movements should work, if they are just NESW then the easiest way would be to think of how that relates to the x and y coordinates.

In particular, moving one step north is `y=y+1; x=x+0;` whilst one step east is `y=y+0; x=x+1;` etc. You can summarise this in a matrix, then randomly choose a row to add to each point's coordinates.

This code uses the same plotting logic, see comments for details:

```
num = 10;                 % number of points
pts = zeros(num, 2);      % Set points coordinates initially to the origin, num x 2 matrix  
movements = [0, 1; 1, 0; -1, 0; 0, -1]; % NESW movements in terms of x and y
stepsize = 1;             % step size at each iteration
figure;                   % create new figure
for k = 1:20
    % Get random movement row for each point, add it to current location
    pts = pts + stepsize*movements(randi([1,4], num, 1),:);   
    % plot and pause
    scatter(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), 'mo');
    drawnow;
    pause(0.1);
end
```

---

You may want to fix the axes limits so that the plot doesn't jump all over the place.

```
for k = 1:20
    % Get random movement row for each point, add it to current location
    pts = pts + stepsize*movements(randi([1,4], num, 1),:);   
    % plot and pause
    scatter(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), 'mo');
    drawnow; 
    xlim([-10,10]); 
    ylim([-10,10]);
    pause(0.1);
end
```